# Linker Error в DLang

Tags: импорт, компоновщик, d

Я новичок в DLang и С образных языках. Решил попробовать знакомство именно с D. Я решил попробовать написать простенькую библиотеку с разными модулями внутри, чтобы посмотреть как это работает в DLang, но столкнулся с проблемой linker error. Вот структура файлов:

```
main.d
mylib
  - myModule1.d
  - myAnotherModule.d
```

Код в main.d

```
package main;
import mylib.myModule1.d

void main()
{
   MyClass classIniter = new MyClass;
}
```

В mylib.myModule1.d:

```
package mylib.myModule1;
import std.stdio;

class World {
  public void Hello() {
     writeln("Hello World!");
  }
}
```

И вот verbose[image: Verbose]

Может проблема в железе? MacOS на Apple Silicon

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: как именно вы собираете проект? я попробовал воспроизвести вашу структуру с dub и у меня проект валится с ошибками компиляции

Comment: Оказывается Я неправильно вообще расположил файлы, а именно компилил через просто dmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем ответ оказывется очень простой и понятный, всё дело именно в одном маленьком файле run.bash, который позволяет компилить файлы сразу через dub. Его можно получить либо вызвав `dub init имяРепозитория` или создав файл run.bash, но тогда его придётся запускать ручками и редактировать тоже. Вот пример как он выглядит: `dmd -run main && mylib`. Но в таком случается требуется поместить папку mylib в source